# How to find top-voted Hacker News posts from a specific domain

Tags: hacker-news

Hacker News now supports filtering stories by domain, e.g.:
https://news.ycombinator.com/from?site=wikipedia.org

Is there any way to sort this list by vote count? Either on HN website or a third-party site?